# Swift CloudKit Query

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm using following code to fetch my CloudKit data:

```
func getShoppingList(completionHandler: @escaping ([ShoppingListEntry]?, Error?) -> ()) {

    var shoppingListEntrys: [ShoppingListEntry] = []

    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ShoppingListEntry", predicate: predicate)

    publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
        else {

            for var value in results! {

                let entry: ShoppingListEntry = ShoppingListEntry()

                entry.amount = value.value(forKey: "amound") as! Int
                entry.description = value.value(forKey: "description") as! String
                entry.isSelected = value.value(forKey: "isSelected") as! Bool

                shoppingListEntrys.append(entry)
            }
        }
    }

    index = shoppingListEntrys.count + 1
    completionHandler(shoppingListEntrys, nil)
}
```

I call this function with this code:

```
cloudKit.getShoppingList() { entrys, error in

        self.shoppingListEntrys = entrys!
        self.tableViewShoppingList.reloadData()
    }
```

My problem is, that the returned shoppingList Array is empty...

Comment: Your call is asynchrone. There are plenty of question about that => Use a closure.

Comment: Do you have an example, I'm not quite sure what to do?

Comment: Read up on asynchronous calls and look at the duplicate linked by @Larme.

Comment: The question name is misleading, but the concepts are the same.